# Get Twitter followers count in PHP without API

Tags: php, twitter

I was wondering of getting Twitter number of followers without using API (just needed to get it at 1 moment) in PHP.

Even I wanted the number of followers of other pages.

Comment: Curious you asked a question  and added an answer same time

Comment: Just wanted to share the code :) don't want to put this on Github or somewhere else.

Comment: It would have been better on github as it can be improved.bug fixes etc

Comment: It is not right to receive data without an API if the API provides such data. Because the HTML code on the Twitter website can be changed at any time and your code will be not valid.

Answer (score 2):

I just developed this little code an it works, so if you just need to get numbers of followers of a Twitter page, use it :

```
function getTwitterFollowers($twitter = 'google', $lang = 'fr') {
    // get page
    $ch = file_get_contents('https://twitter.com/'. $twitter .'?lang='. $lang);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($ch);
    $finder = new DomXPath($doc);
    $classname="ProfileNav-stat";
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

    // translate followers in each lang to replace it
    $langs = array(
        'fr' => 'Abonnés',
        'en' => 'Followers',
    );

    return str_replace($langs[$lang] . $langs[$lang], '', str_replace(' ', '', preg_replace('/\R/', '', $nodes[2]->textContent)));
}

echo getTwitterFollowers('google', 'fr');
```